# docker-compose is trying to access proc files

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, procfs

Docker-compose is giving me this error and I have no idea why:

```
> docker-compose -f local.yml build
Step 8/21 : RUN find . -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -r {} \+
 ---> Running in 9da1be4e2ae5
find: './proc/1/map_files': Operation not permitted
find: './proc/6/map_files': Operation not permitted
ERROR: Service 'base' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c find . -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -r {} \+' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I looked up `proc` files and understood that they are kernel files and thus some will only be readable by root. I tried to run it with `sudo` and still the same problem.

I then tried to reinstall both `docker-ce` and `docker-compose`. They are now both latest version:

```
> docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.17.0, build ac53b73
docker-py version: 2.5.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016


> docker version 
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:46 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:39:27 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

And the error is still there. I've also tried to remove the tun0 bridge:

```
sudo ip link delete tun0
```

My user is in the docker group.

My system:

```
Linux lab 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The docker file source: https://github.com/louisgv/concept-to-clinic/blob/master/compose/base/Dockerfile-dev

Comment: You run `find .`, can I assume that `.` is "/" in your context?  I guess so since you have not specified a running directory.  Can't you be more specific as to the starting directory of your find to avoid going into /proc?  These pycache files are probably not spread throughout the system.

Comment: I ended up removing the line that was trying to find pycache...